# QT Screen switching with Scrolling effect (ex:- Scrolling from first screen to second screen)

Tags: qt

I’m developijng a QT UI application. where in, The main Screen is shown on the launch of QT application. And later on button press event the Second Screen has to be shown and so on.

But to switch the screens from Screen 1 to Screen 2 the scrolling effects has to be show to the user, the scrolling effect can be from moving first to second from left to right(or from right to left).

As of now i have implemented using QT animation framework.

can any one please suggest me If there is any other way to achive this ?

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance
Varun

Comment: That would seem to be a reasonable way to do it - what problems have you experienced or are you just exploring other options?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I have a multiThreaded application UI Thread with higher priority and Worker thread with NormalPriority. The Worker thread continuously listens to the events from other applications throught out the life time.

When i start an animation of switching the screen by setting the animation duration of setDuration(1500); the animation happens smoothly in the UI thread. only if the worker thread does not receive any events. And I can see the chocking effect in the animation if the worker thread receives any event form other applications during the animation.

The reason is, While the UI thread is animating it switches to the worker thread if the worker thread receives an event resulting in chocking effect in the UI.

If i use the scrolling of widgets instead of animation. than in this case the UI thread does not switch to the worker thread untill it process all the events in its event queue. resulting in smooth scrolling. To achive this I’m scrolling 10 pixel ever time in a event loop. so that i can see the smooth scrolling.

Please do suggest me if you have any other scenarios(or other way) which i can try ? So that i can see smooth animation with out chocking effects.